# Dart. Decode json double gives null

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a custom object in dart that I convert to json, save as shared preference, then decode it when I need it.

Here is the class:

```
class MaslulModel {
  final String name;
  final int numberOfMonths;
  final int totalAmount;
  final int maslulIndex;
  final double interest;

  MaslulModel(this.name, this.numberOfMonths, this.totalAmount, this.maslulIndex, this.interest);

  String getDetails(){

    String output = '2124. Maslul Details: Maslul name: ${name}. Maslul Index: ${this.maslulIndex}. Total amount: ${this.totalAmount}. Number of months: ${this.numberOfMonths}. Interest: ${this.interest}';

    return output;


  }


  // To save list as pref

  factory MaslulModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return MaslulModel(
      jsonData['name'],
      jsonData['numberOfMonths'],
      jsonData['totalAmount'],
      jsonData['maslulIndex'],
      jsonData['interest;'],
   );
  }

  static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(MaslulModel maslulModel) => {

    'name': maslulModel.name,
    'numberOfMonths': maslulModel.numberOfMonths,
    'totalAmount': maslulModel.totalAmount,
    'maslulIndex': maslulModel.maslulIndex,
    'interest': maslulModel.interest,

  };


  static String encode(List<MaslulModel> musics) => json.encode(
    musics
        .map<Map<String, dynamic>>((music) => MaslulModel.toMap(music))
        .toList(),
  );

  static List<MaslulModel> decode(String musics) =>
      (json.decode(musics) as List<dynamic>)
          .map<MaslulModel>((item) => MaslulModel.fromJson(item))
          .toList();


}
```

Now, when I use the decode function, all the values are saved perfectly, by the interest field, which is a double, returns null.

For example, the string that is returned is:

```
[{"name":"ברמן","numberOfMonths":5,"totalAmount":500,"maslulIndex":0,"interest":5.0}]
```

Which is great, showing that the interest is 5.0 (a double). But when this is decode, the interest on the object is null.

Why would this be.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonData['interest;'],` is looking for a key of `interest;`.  Didn't think it'd be that simple, huh?

Comment: It's why code review is mandatory, and should definitely be someone besides you!